# jQuery when done or fail not triggering

Tags: jquery, jquery-deferred

What have I missed here:

```
var Services = {
    TestService: {
        init: function() {
            var promises = [];
            for (var i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
                var def = $.Deferred();
                Services.TestService.test(i).then(function(a) {
                    def.resolve();
                }, function() {
                    console.log("test rejected");
                    def.reject();
                });
                promises.push(def.promise());
            }

            $.when.apply($, promises).then(function() {
                console.log("Finished all promises");
            }, function() {
                console.log("eror");
            });
        },
        test: function(i) {
            var def = $.Deferred();
            setTimeout(function() {
                console.log("test timeout expired: " + i.toString());
                def.resolve("ok: " + i.toString());
            }, 1000);
            return def.promise();
        }
    }
}

Services.TestService.init();
```

It only prints:

```
test timeout expired: 0
test timeout expired: 1
test timeout expired: 2
```

Why doesn't `when` done or fail (implemented as then) fire up. What detail have I missed? Using jQuery 1.9.1. (`<script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.js"></script>`)

Comment: You redefine `def` inside `for` loop. Because deferred is async, only last one is resolved/rejected. Using `let def` would fix it or redefine `def` scope: https://jsfiddle.net/ksexnrpe/  or using `let`:  https://jsfiddle.net/jj0b9mdk

Comment: @A.Wolff I believe your comment qualifies as answer, you could post it. Could I ask why next code works only if sendCommand returns function() {var d = $.Deferred()}. Why does it have to return function as sendCommand itself is function. https://jsfiddle.net/5kbttz27/2